# AlertDialog android background

Tags: android, background

Открываю AlertDialog, хочу чтобы был размытый фон следующим кодом:

```
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilderForBack = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                dialogBuilderForBack.setTitle("Title");
                dialogBuilderForBack.setMessage("message");
                dialogBuilderForBack.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                AlertDialog alertDialogForBack = dialogBuilderForBack.create();

                alertDialogForBack.setView(dialogView);
                Bitmap map1 = takeScreenShot(getActivity());
                Bitmap fast1 = fastblur(map1, 10);
                final Drawable draw1 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),fast1);
                //alertDialogForBack.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(draw1);
                alertDialogForBack.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                alertDialogForBack.show();
```

Открывается всё отлично!

Код методов для размытия экрана брал [От сюда](https://overcoder.net/q/334658/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8-alertdialog)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только раскоментирую строчку

```
 //alertDialogForBack.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(draw1);
```

Происходит следующее:

[image: Происходит вот это]

На такой способ как

```
alertDialogForBack.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Не реагирует! Что случается? почему добавление фона меняет поведение алерта?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов размытия фона под диалогом нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421723/alertdialog-with-blur-background-in-position-center), вот как должна выглядеть активность:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  AlertDialog dialogWhichDisplayAlert;
    private  Dialog fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        //  fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.setContentView(R.layout.fakealert); // removed the content so not visible



        new BlurAsyncTask().execute();

    }

    class BlurAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Bitmap> {


        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

            Bitmap map  = AppUtils.takeScreenShot(MainActivity.this);
            Bitmap fast = new BlurView().fastBlur(map, 10);
            return fast;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null){
                final Drawable draw=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),result);
                Window window = fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.getWindow();
                window.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
                window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.show();


                // real one
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
                builder.setTitle("Lets Blur");
                builder.setMessage("This is Blur Demo");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.dismiss();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.dismiss();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                dialogWhichDisplayAlert = builder.create();

                // position real dialogWhichDisplayAlert using Gravity.CENTER;
                dialogWhichDisplayAlert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialogWhichDisplayAlert.getWindow().getAttributes();
                wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                dialogWhichDisplayAlert.show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

так же есть [библиотека](https://github.com/byvlstr/blurdialog) для ваших целей. Подобные вопросы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865033/how-to-blur-a-dialog-activity-background) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802320/how-to-set-blur-background-when-dialog-create). Так же я бы вам советовал посмотреть в сторону обычного Dialog. У него можно установить свою разметку, которая будет похожа на системную, а потом установить размытый фон для подложки. Второй вариант:

```
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(WordCube.this)
   .setTitle(WordCube.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
   .setMessage(s)
   .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
   .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_close, null)
   .show();
```

и дальше устанавливаем размытие:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Вот есть туториалы [1](https://androidexample365.com/easily-have-blurred-and-transparent-background-effect-on-your-android-views/) и [2](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-blurring-and-dimming-background-windows-from-dialogs/).